# Graphite-webapp not showing graph

Tags: monitoring, graphite

[Graphite Web UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM5Dv.png)

I can view the metrics in the tree but cannot view the graph. Does anyone have any inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open image on separate tab - it will give you error message.

Comment: I tried opening the image and it did not give any error it gives a small white box.

Comment: Try Right click - Open image in new Tab in Chrome. Or Right click - Copy image location, File - New tab - Ctrl+V - Enter - in Firefox

Comment: Yes I tried opening it that way. The url was :https://172.16.0.150/render/?width=586&height=308&_salt=1490635799.706 It has a black background with a tiny white square.